# Code isn't starting a random activity - Android/Java

Tags: java, android, android-intent, random, android-activity

I have written some code to try and make a random activity start. I will post the code below:

```
private void setupMusicQuestion() {
        ImageButton musicquestion = (ImageButton)      findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

        musicquestion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int min = 1;
                int max = 10;
                ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for(int i = min; i <= max; i++) list.add(i);
                Collections.shuffle(list);

                Integer x = list.get(0);


                switch(x){
                 case 1:
                     startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MusicOne.class));
                  break;
                 case 2:
                     startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MusicTwo.class));
                  break;
                 case 3:
                     startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MusicThree.class));
                  break;
                 case 4:
                     startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MusicFour.class));
                  break;
                 case 5:
                     startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MusicFive.class));
                  break;
                 case 6:
                     startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MusicSix.class));
                  break;
                 case 7:
                     startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MusicSeven.class));
                  break;
                 case 8:
                     startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MusicEight.class));
                  break;
                 case 9:
                     startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MusicNine.class));
                  break;
                 case 10:
                     startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MusicTen.class));
                  break;
                 }
```

However, when I run this program it always loads up the activity in position 1. Can you see why this is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I fixed it, it was a stupid mistake. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
YOU HAVE TO CHECK  AndroidManifest.xml  AND CHNAGE LAUNCHER ACTIVITY CONIGURATION

<activity android:name="demo1.MyActivity" android:label="test APP"
      android:icon="@drawable/myicon">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use random numbers beteen 1 to 10 like:

```
            int min = 1;
            int max = 10;


            int x = Math.random()*9+1;


            switch(x){
             case 1:
                 startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MusicOne.class));
              break;
             case 2:
                 startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MusicTwo.class));
              break;
             case 3:
                 startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MusicThree.class));
              break;
             case 4:
                 startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MusicFour.class));
              break;
             case 5:
                 startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MusicFive.class));
              break;
             case 6:
                 startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MusicSix.class));
              break;
             case 7:
                 startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MusicSeven.class));
              break;
             case 8:
                 startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MusicEight.class));
              break;
             case 9:
                 startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MusicNine.class));
              break;
             case 10:
                 startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MusicTen.class));
              break;
             }
```